# CSS: How to have multiple counters in nested counters

Tags: css

So I am trying to use nested counters in CSS but I am not quite familiar with how it works, This is what I have so far,

[image: This is what I have so far]

But what I was hoping to happen is that every time there is an unordered list, when I start an ordered list it resets back to 1. 2. 3. and so on perhaps similar to this

[image: Something Like This]

https://codepen.io/jojonmarijon/pen/OJZZPBK?editors=1100

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <ol>
    <li>AA</li>
    <li>BB</li>
    <li>CC</li>
    <ol>
      <li>AAA</li>
      <li>BBB</li>
      <li>CCC</li>
      <ul>
        <li>AAAA</li>
        <li>BBBB</li>
        <ol>
          <li>AAAAA</li>
          <li>BBBBB</li>
          <li>CCCCC</li>
        </ol>
        <li>CCCC</li>
      </ul>
      <li>DDD</li>
    </ol>
  </ol>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    ol {
        counter-reset: section;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul {
        counter-reset: section;
    }

    ol > li {
        counter-increment: section;
    }

    ol > li::marker {
        content: counters(section, ".") ". ";
        left: -4px;
    }

    ul > li:before {
        counter-increment: section;
        content: '';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a generic solution is possible with just CSS at the moment: `counter-reset: <name>` will create a nested counter if there is already a counter with `<name>` in the hierarchy. And there's no way to access the parent, or "unnest" the parent counter. You'd need a counter with a different name to achieve your result.

So I think you'll need to choose between 2 sub-optimal solutions:

1. Implement it in JS
2. Support it only for up to `n` levels deep, for some low level of `n`. E.g. something like this:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol > li {
  counter-increment: section;
}

ol > li::marker {
  content: counters(section, ".") ". ";
  left: -4px;
}

/* Level 1 */

ul ol {
  counter-reset: nested;
}

ul ol > li {
  counter-increment: nested;
}

ul ol > li::marker {
  content: counters(nested, ".") ". ";
}

/* level 2 */

ul ul ol {
  counter-reset: nested2;
}

ul ul ol > li {
  counter-increment: nested2;
}

ul ul ol > li::marker {
  content: counters(nested2, ".") ". ";
}

/* etc. */
```

See also: https://codepen.io/Tiddo/pen/vYjjRRx?editors=1100

I think that in practice, you likely only need to support it 3-5 levels deep at most, so you might be able to get away with the hardcoded solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I hope you don't mind if I ask for a little more help, 
I'm curious how you would implement this with JS?

Comment: It depends. If you're using a framework like React/Vue/Angular or something then I would create "wrapper components" (something like `<my-ol>`) that keeps track of the indices internally, and resets when needed. The details of course depend on the framework. In vanilla-js, it's a bit more tricky, you'd need to iterate through all `ol`s on load, and figure out the correct numbers. Something like this: https://codepen.io/Tiddo/pen/BaxxVeW Small note on this: this quick implementation assumes that `<ul>` and `<ol>` only have `<li>` as children, and also that the lists never update.